# Dictionary comprehension creating unexpected result

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning Python, currently dictionary comprehension. I am playing around with different ideas just to see what I get and I'm getting one I really don't understand. Any help understanding what I'm doing wrong would be really appreciated.

Specifically, this code:

```
test_dict = {key: val
        for key in ['a','b','c']
        for val in range(3)}
print(test_dict)
```

Produces the following dictionary: `{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}`

I'm expecting: `{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}`

When I run this quick loop:

```
for val in range(3):
   print(val)
```

I get:

```
0
1
2
```

Is there a reason every dictionary key is getting the same value, the final value of the range iterator?

I'm running Python 3.6.5 via Anaconda / Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's blow up your dict comprehension; it's equivalent to the following:

```
test_dict = {}
for key in ['a','b','c']:
    for val in range(3):
        test_dict[key] = val
```

So, for each key, you perform three different assignments into your dictionary. Naturally, only the last one is retained.

To get the result you want, just assign ho each key once. An obvious way in this case is to use `enumerate()` to number the items in the sequence, then use that for the value.

```
test_dict = {key: val for val, key in enumerate(['a','b','c'])}
```

For the general case of any two sequences, use `zip()`:

```
test_dict = {key: val for key, val in zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], range(3))}
```

Actually, since the `dict` constructor is happy to consume a sequence of key/value pairs, you can write that this way:

```
test_dict = dict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], range(3)))
```

Comment: Good answer, but I would add some discussion about the general case, where you would use `zip`,

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent to a 2 nested `for` loops, for each `key` you effectively run successively the command `test_dict[key] = val` for all `val`, only the last one will remain.

You probably want this instead:

```
test_dict = {key: val for key,val in zip('abc', range(3))}
```

or directly

```
test_dict = dict(zip('abc', range(3)))
```